# Image not forwarded by node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, request

I got a minimal node.js server where the images for a website are loaded from another webserver. For that I parse the image/get and request it from another server with the lib "request". The problem is, that the images do not show.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

function rootMyWebSideGetImages(req,res)
{
    var urlpart = req.url.replace('/mywebside','');
    var options = {
        url: 'http://otherwebside.net'+urlpart,
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            res.setHeader('content-type',response.headers['content-type']);
            res.send(body); 
            console.log("get IMAGE: "+options.url);
        }
    });
}

app.get('/mywebside/theme/images*', rootMyWebSideGetImages);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() 
{
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

The code is more complex as there are different gets for different pathes. As long as I request text or html it works fine. But images do not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get image from request.
For example stream it to file (from docs):

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png')))
```

then make sure it is file.
Log errors from request, maybe there is some problem.

Check express helper method for download files:

```
res.download(path [, filename] [, fn])
```

Comment: then, if this is image send it from server by res.download and don't set header.

Comment: I can try it, but it does not help as solution as I do not want to cache the image.

Comment: ok, but then we will now that problem is with send method or headers